# Getting the null value while accessing current route name in Laravel Framework 7.5.2

Tags: laravel

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    $name = Route::currentRouteName();;
    dd($name);
});
```

I tried to fetch the name but it returns me null value.

Comment: I would suggest having a specific question that you are asking

Answer (score 0):

have you try

```
$uri = $request->path();
```

ex.

```
Route::get('about', function (Request $request) {
    $uri = $request->path();
    dd($uri);
});
```

include header

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```